# how to create a background process , it will disable the physical volume buttons when running

Tags: java, android

My boss ask me to develop an app which have to be always on the user screen. I have to disable the three Android native buttons (back, home and history buttons).

How can I do that ? Create a custom launcher ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't, and that's by design.

Comment: hi ! how can i create a background process and disable the physical volume , when it is running

Answer (score 0):

In general you can't really do the things you mentioned above, at least there are no official supported APIs.

However, there can be legitimate use cases where one would benefit from this kind of applications, and Android provides something for this.

Have a look into [Lock Task Mode](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/lock-task-mode) and [ScreenPinning](https://support.google.com/android/answer/6118421).